# Installing HDFS interface package for julia

Tags: hadoop, julia

I am new to Julia language and found it very interesting. As it says it is hadoop ready I wanted to test this using my local hadoop cluster. I installed latest version of julia in my debian 32 bit machine and wrote few simple scripts, sort of Hello world stuffs. Now, I have pulled HDFS and YARN interface package from the below site
https://github.com/JuliaParallel/HDFS.jl
https://github.com/JuliaParallel/Elly.jl

Do not know How to install these in my machine and use these package for querying HDFS cluster and run few map-reduce tasks.

Any pointers will be very much helpful here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does `Pkg.add("HDFS")` & `Pkg.add("Elly")` work? [Docs here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/packages/)

Comment: julia> Pkg.add("HDFS")
INFO: Initializing package repository /home/bala/.julia/v0.3
INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
ERROR: failed process: Process(`git clone -q -b metadata-v2 git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl METADATA`, ProcessExited(128)) [128]
 in pipeline_error at process.jl:502
 in run at ./process.jl:479
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:46
 in cd at ./file.jl:20
 in init at ./pkg/dir.jl:44
 in __cd#229__ at ./pkg/dir.jl:28
 in add at pkg.jl:20

Comment: I will look into the link that is pointed above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems I am having a problem in git/curl. I will fix this and hopefully, the issue will rectify then. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Ok, Now, I have fixed my git. But still the command Pkg.add("Elly") is not successful.

Comment: julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: No packages to install, update or remove

julia> Pkg.add("Elly")
ERROR: Elly can't be installed because it has no versions that support 0.3.11 of julia. You may need to update METADATA by running `Pkg.update()`
 in wait at task.jl:51
 in sync_end at ./task.jl:311
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:319
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:71
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:28
 in cd at ./file.jl:20
 in __cd#229__ at ./pkg/dir.jl:28
 in add at pkg.jl:20

Comment: as the error says `it has no versions that support 0.3.11 of julia`. [Elly](http://pkg.julialang.org) only supports julia v0.4. you can use a nightly build version or build julia from source code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gnimuc Key, I took a nightly build version (0.4) and I could install Elly package

Comment: If your answer answered your question, please mark this as answered so it does not show up as unanswered. Thanks!